# Awk command has unexpected results when comparing two files

Tags: awk, text-processing

I am using an awk command to compare the first column in two file.

I want to take col1 of file1 and if there is a match in col1 of file2, update the "date updated" in the last column. If there is no match, I want to append the entire line of file1 to file2 and append a "date updated" value to that line as well. Here is the command I'm currently using:

```
awk 'FNR == NR { f1[$1] = $0; next } 
    $1 in f1 { print; delete f1[$1] } 
    END { for (user in f1) print f1[user] }' file1 file2
```

File1:

```
tnash,172.2,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW
jhwagner,169.4,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW
steadmah,161.1,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW
guillwt,158.3,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW
mwinebra,122.2,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW
jbomba,100.0,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW
mschrode,161.1,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW
```

File2:

```
jbomba,114.0,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeOLD
mschrode,104.0,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeOLD
deleteme,192.0,random,serv01,datetimeOLD        #<---- Needs to be removed: WORKS!
```

Expected Output:(order does not matter)

```
tnash,172.2,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW
jhwagner,169.4,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW
steadmah,161.1,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW
guillwt,158.3,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW
mwinebra,122.2,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW
jbomba,100.0,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeOLD      #<---- NEED THIS VALUE
mschrode,161.1,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeOLD    #<---- NEED THIS VALUE
```

Current Output:(order does not matter)

```
tnash,172.2,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW
jhwagner,169.4,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW
steadmah,161.1,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW
guillwt,158.3,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW
mwinebra,122.2,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW
jbomba,100.0,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW      #<----WRONG OUTPUT
mschrode,161.1,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW    #<----WRONG OUTPUT
```

The Logic Broken Down:

```
If $usr/col1 in file2 does NOT exist in file1
     remove entire line from file2
     (ex: line3 in file2, user: deleteme)
If $usr/col1 in file1 does NOT exist in file2
      append entire line to file2
      (ex: lines 1-5 in file1)
```

So the issue is, when there IS a match between the two files, I need to keep the information from file2, not the information from file1. In the output examples above you'll see I need to keep the datetimeOLD from file2 along with the new information from file1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set field separator to comma, and read `file2` first:

```
$ awk -F',' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} $1 in a{print a[$1];next} 1' file2 file1
tnash,172.2,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW
jhwagner,169.4,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW
steadmah,161.1,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW
guillwt,158.3,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW
mwinebra,122.2,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeNEW
jbomba,114.0,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeOLD
mschrode,104.0,plasma-de+,serv01,datetimeOLD
```

Comment: That works, just curious how you were able to reduce the awk command so much. Can you explain your simplification compared to mine please?

Comment: @colm Mine reads `file2` into array `a` mapping first column to the whole record first, then while reading `file1`, if first column exists in `a`, it prints the corresponding record from `file2` (i.e `a[$1]`), otherwise it prints the current record. Yours were longer and more complex because it reads `file1` first, which requires you to print everything left in `a` using a loop at the end. Hope this explanation is clear